# SQL Server - Change JSON string value to array

Tags: json, sql-server

I have a SQL Server Table with a JSON column. In it, I have a property 'Code' that contained a string with one value. Now, I want that 'Code' to be an Array to be able to contain more than one strings.

How can I update all my table values to change the property to an array?

```
"Code" : null --> "Code" : []
"Code" : "XX" --> "Code" : ["XX"]
```

Comment: Assuming every object *currently* contains only scalar values for `Code`, `UPDATE MyTable SET jsonColumn = JSON_MODIFY(jsonColumn, '$.Code', CONCAT('[', JSON_VALUE(jsonColumn, '$.Code'), ']'))`. If we cannot assume this things get much trickier.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, that would work with int, but no with strings, as it loses the "
"Code" : "XX" would be changed to "Code" : [XX] and I want it to be "Code" : ["XX"]

Comment: Oh, right. Yeah, that's quite a bit more complicated, since we have to get `JSON_QUERY` and/or `OPENJSON` involved. Oh well, that's why it's not an answer. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try to modify the stored `JSON` as text using `OPENJSON()` with default schema to get the type of the `$.Code` part:

Sample data:

```
SELECT *
INTO Data
FROM (VALUES
   (CONVERT(nvarchar(max), N'{"Code": "XX"}')),
   (CONVERT(nvarchar(max), N'{"Code": null}')),
   (CONVERT(nvarchar(max), N'{"Code": 1}')),
   (CONVERT(nvarchar(max), N'{"Code": []}')),
   (CONVERT(nvarchar(max), N'{"Code": {}}'))
) d (JsonColumn)
```

Statement:

```
UPDATE d
SET JsonColumn = JSON_MODIFY(
   JsonColumn, 
   '$.Code', 
   JSON_QUERY(CONCAT('[', j.[value], ']'))
)
FROM Data d
OUTER APPLY (
   SELECT 
      CASE 
         WHEN [type] = 0 THEN ''
         WHEN [type] = 1 THEN CONCAT('"', STRING_ESCAPE([value], 'json'), '"')
         WHEN [type] = 2 THEN [value]
         ELSE '"not a scalar value"'
      END AS [value]
   FROM OPENJSON(d.JsonColumn, '$')
   WHERE [key] = 'Code'
) j
```

Result:

```
JsonColumn
--------------------------------
{"Code": ["XX"]}
{"Code": []}
{"Code": [1]}
{"Code": ["not a scalar value"]}
{"Code": ["not a scalar value"]}
```

You may consider the @JeroenMostert's comment and use something like this:

```
UPDATE d
SET JsonColumn = JSON_MODIFY(
   JsonColumn, 
   '$.Code', 
   JSON_QUERY(CONCAT('[', j.[value], ']'))
)
FROM Data d
OUTER APPLY (
   SELECT IIF ([type] = 1, CONCAT('"', STRING_ESCAPE([value], 'json'), '"'), [value]) AS [value]
   FROM OPENJSON(d.JsonColumn, '$')
   WHERE [key] = 'Code'
) j
```

Comment: This can be made a bit shorter by using the `CASE [type] WHEN...` syntax (same semantics, of course). Also, don't forget to `STRING_ESCAPE([value], 'json')` in the case of strings.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, thanks, `STRING_ESCAPE()` is very important.

Comment: The "not a scalar value" thing seems unwise (and unnecessary); simply interpolating `value` again should usually work. In fact, `IIF ([type] = 1, CONCAT('"', STRING_ESCAPE([value], 'json'), '"'), [value])` should cover everything, since really only strings are special.

Comment: Yeah, mine is still going on or I would have posted an answer myself. :P